# UICollectionViewCell GetCell getting called twice

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS application, I am having a horizontally UIcollectionview. when scrolling from the last image to the previous image, the following method is getting called twice with different IndexPath values.

Code

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

Please guide me to understand the issue.

Thanks

Comment: The path requested is based upon cell’s position in the collection view, assumably it is pre-requesting the next cell that will be visible if the user keeps scrolling back but you did not provide much detail in your question.

Comment: @SushiHangover I am pretty sure he is unaware of the feature in iOS that creates the next list cell in advance and hence I think we should close this.

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, Thaks for the comment. But, how can I prevent from calling twice because it's only happening to when scrolling  from the last image to the previous image (e.g - 8th image is the last image, and when scrolling to 7th image, the function is getting called twice. First time it's returning the 7th index and next time it's returning 5th index)

Comment: The main issue is that when i am in last image & scroll to next (where therer is no image) the GetCell function is getting called and returining the 7th indexpath value. Isn't it a wrong value returned by the function ?

Comment: please check that you have provided a custom height for your collectionview cell, and set the row height of collection view as same instead of automatic.